# How I could redirect all my traffic to Tor network?

Tags: mac, network

I need to redirect all my traffic to Tor network. I have just installed Vidalia, but I think that I have not correctly configured my Tor-client. I have a Java desktop client that have to access to a website. This allows us to connect 50 times then it reject our connection. I would like to use Tor to  create more conecctions. How I can configure my tor-client correctly? Is there any online how-to? Are there other solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't redirect **ALL** traffic into TOR - if you mean all traffic at the IP level. (so all icmp, tcp and udp traffic), because you need basic routing via the internet - e.g. you need route TOR packets to neigbohrs. TOR is an VIRTUAL network using onion routing (SOCKS), so you need explicitly route packets into TOR.

If you mean "route ALL web-browsing traffic" into tor-network, the easiest way is using Firefox and get a torbutton plugin into firefox.

After installing the plugin, it is enough:

1. start Vidalia, and
2. activate "torbutton" in the Firefox. (bottom right corner).

BTW, it is a good practice:
  - use Safari (or Chrome) for you common browsing, and
  - use Firefox for anonymous things (you can setup Firefox start into "private browsing" mode, you should disable cookies and so on...

BEWARE - if your browser gets a cookie via TOR and after it send this cookie via normal browsing session - you get the idea :)