# How to easily forward/redirect all network traffics through local socks port 1080?

Tags: network, vpn, proxy

How to easily forward/redirect all network traffics through local socks port 1080? I did google this before asking question. I found [this link](https://superuser.com/questions/802967/how-can-i-make-sure-all-my-macs-tcp-traffic-goes-through-a-socks5-proxy) and [this link](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/17059/how-i-could-redirect-all-my-traffic-to-tor-network) and others too. But there is no simple solution. 
(The system preferences network proxy setup just don't work for all apps. ) 
Is that so hard to do it? I think just some iptables rules should do it. (although I don't know what is the equivalent `iptables` command in macos, maybe `pfctl`?). Can anyone show me some simple shell scripts which can achieve this? Thank you very much.

Comment: This sounds like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/).  Consider editing your question to describe the *initial* issue that is causing you to look for this particular solution.

Comment: @Allan this is not an XY Problem to me. I just want to redirect all network traffics through local socks proxy port 1080. That is my problem and I don't know how to achieve it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since nobody posts a shell script (or easy way) to solve my question, I posted my current workaround solution:

1. Install virtualbox
2. Install openwrt as the guest OS to virtualbox
3. Configure the openwrt to become a router which has the lan IP of 192.168.56.2. The lan interface is a Host-only adapter. The wan interface is Bridged adapter.
4. Configure the openwrt router to do the transparent proxy job that I want.
5. Change both gateway and DNS to 192.168.56.2 in the host.

   - to change the gateway: `sudo route change default 192.168.56.2`
   - to change the DNS: must use the UI way. System Preferences --> Network --> Adavanced --> DNS

That's all. So far so good.

Answer (score 1):

@sgon00, Thank you for an idea and solution! I can't comment, but I want to share a bit of continuation here:

To use your Virtual OpenWRT router from different VM on the same host you should:

1. On OpenWRT VM follow the intruction: https://openwrt.org/docs/guide-user/virtualization/virtualbox-vm

but instead of adding phisical adapter (eth0, wlps0) (3d adapter in manual), add virtual one (virbr0) as Bridged Adapter (Linux).

then ssh to openwrt:

```
root@OpenWrt:~# uci set network.lan.type='bridge' 
root@OpenWrt:~# uci set network.lan.proto='static' 
root@OpenWrt:~# uci set network.lan.netmask='255.255.255.0' 
root@OpenWrt:~# uci set network.lan.ip6assign='60' 
root@OpenWrt:~# uci set network.lan.ipaddr='192.168.1.1'
```

uci commit && reboot

2. On another VM you want to route over OpenWRT:

add the same virtual adapter (virbr0) as on step 1 the same way. Start VM, it should automatticaly connect to the DHCP on [1] and connect to internet.